# batch file MOVE command

Tags: batch-file, ftp

Hopefully someone can help or point me in the right direction, I have a batch file that currently gets a csv file from an FTP server.  I need to add a command that after the file has been copied to my server, the csv file in the root directory '/' of the FTP server gets moved to a /'processed' folder within the FTP directory.
I was using: echo mdelete *.* >> delftp.dat
but I now want to move the file to a folder called 'processed'.
thanks.